# Getting parent of AST node in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm working with Abstract Syntax Trees in Python 3. The `ast` library gives many ways to get children of the node (you can use `iter_child_nodes()` or `walk()`) but no ways to get **parent** of one. Also, every node has links to its children, but it hasn't links to its parent.

**How I can get the parent of AST node** if I don't want to write some plugin to `ast` library?

What is the most correct way to do this?

Comment: You could traverse the tree and create a reverse lookup table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might create some hash table associating AST nodes to AST nodes and scan (recursively) your topmost AST tree to register in that hash table the parent of each node.

Answer (score 35):

Here's some actual code:

```
for node in ast.walk(root):
    for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(node):
        child.parent = node
```

There's no need for a hash table, you can just put an attribute directly on the node.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'UnaryOp' object has no attribute 'parent'`

Comment: @MartinThoma ask a new question and link it here

Comment: Never mind; I was dumb. I just accessed `child.parent` and did not add the attribute as you did in your code.

Comment: I now run into the issue that it's unclear to me [how to properly annotate this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65559257/562769). I'd be happy if you could have a look 

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `ast.NodeTransformer` to achieve this:

**Code:**

```py
import ast


class Parentage(ast.NodeTransformer):
    # current parent (module)
    parent = None

    def visit(self, node):
        # set parent attribute for this node
        node.parent = self.parent
        # This node becomes the new parent
        self.parent = node
        # Do any work required by super class 
        node = super().visit(node)
        # If we have a valid node (ie. node not being removed)
        if isinstance(node, ast.AST):
            # update the parent, since this may have been transformed 
            # to a different node by super
            self.parent = node.parent
        return node
```

**Usage:**

```py
module = Parentage().visit(ast.parse('def _(): ...'))
assert module.parent is None
assert module.body[0].parent is module
```

Later on when you want to edit the tree in some other way, you can subclass:

```py
class SomeRefactoring(Parentage):
    def visit_XXX(node):
        self.generic_visit(node)
        f'do some work on {node.parent} here if you want'
        return node
```

**Note:**

Its worth noting that some nodes can have multiple parents. For example:

```py
module = ast.parse("warnings.warn('Dinosaurs!')")
func = module.body[0].value.func
name, ctx = ast.iter_child_nodes(func)
assert ctx is next(ast.iter_child_nodes(name))
```

Which shows that the same `ast.Load` node `ctx` has two parents - `func` and `name`. The parent will be set by the last position that the node appears in in the tree.

Comment: Could you add comments / explain the logic of your Parentage.visit() function in more detail? I understood it after staring at it for a while, but some more explanation might be useful for other passers by :)

Comment: Added some explanation. Hopefully it's a bit more clear now. :)

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be really be a plugin, but you can always write a function which adds a weakref to parent in every child.