# How do I annotate a type which has an extra attribute with mypy?

Tags: python, mypy, type-annotation

I have an `ast.UnaryOp` object, but I manually added a `parent` attribute (see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43311383/562769)). How do I annotate this in a function?

I currently simply have:

```py
def _get_sim206(node: ast.UnaryOp):
    if isinstance(node.parent, ast.If):
        return False
    return True
```

But mypy complains (rightfully so) that `ast.UnaryOp` does not have the `parent` attribute.

How can I tell mypy that the `node` is not `ast.UnaryOp` but `ast.UnaryOp + parent attribute`?

### My Try

I've created my own `UnaryOp` class which has a parent attribute. I can use this for type-casting:

```py
class UnaryOp(ast.UnaryOp):
    def __init__(self, orig: ast.UnaryOp) -> None:
        self.op = orig.op
        self.operand = orig.operand
        self.lineno = orig.lineno
        self.col_offset = orig.col_offset
        self.parent: ast.Expr = orig.parent  # type: ignore
```

The downside of it is that I need to type cast in a lot of places and that I introduced `Any`. I would prefer if I could just state somewhere that all `ast.*` types in that file do have a `parent` attribute

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could use `isinstance()` with [protocol](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html) decorated with the [@runtime_checkable](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#using-isinstance-with-protocols), that will check at runtime that all protocol members are defined and also ensure statical correctness.

```
from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable, cast
import ast


@runtime_checkable
class ParentProto(Protocol):
    parent: ast.AST
    

def foo(node: ast.UnaryOp):
    if isinstance(node, ParentProto):
        # use node.parent
        p = node.parent
        l = node.lineno
```

```
# assignment
g = ast.UnaryOp()
cast(ParentProto, g).parent = ast.If()
```

Comment: Oh, nice! I always forget about `protocol`

Comment: Is it possible to annotate that a parameter should be an `ast.UnaryOp` and an `ParentProto`? (not Union, this is a logical "OR" of the types)

Comment: As far as I know, it's impossible, mypy has difficulty with representing of intersection of types, in contrast to union.