# Generating a call graph using NetworkX and the ast module

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to generate a call graph from files containing source code using Python's `ast` module and the `networkx` library. Assumptions are as follows:

- Files only contain function definitions and no class definitions
- Function definitions may be nested to arbitrary depth, so inner functions are allowed
- Lambda functions are to be ignored
- Only calls to functions located within the current file/modules are relevant

Given, the above, I came up with the following code. First I walk the entire tree and collect the `FunctionDef` elements into a list. I also add the `FunctionDef` names into the NetworkX `DiGraph`. I then loop over the `ast.FunctionDef` elements I collected, `ast.walk` through each of them and add an edge to the NetworkX `DiGraph` corresponding to each function call. Finally I use NetworkX's plotting functionality to create a drawing of the call graph:

```py
import ast
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("filename", type=str, help="filename containing source code")
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.filename) as fs:
    source = fs.read()
    tree = ast.parse(source)

function_defs = []
calls = []
G = nx.DiGraph()

for node in ast.walk(tree):
    if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef):
        function_defs.append(node)
        G.add_node(node.name)

for function_def in function_defs:
    for node in ast.walk(function_def):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Call) and isinstance(node.func, ast.Name):
            G.add_edge(function_def.name, node.func.id)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Here's an example of application, given a file `call-graph-example.py` as follows:

```py
def g(x):
    return h(x)

def h(x):
    return x*7

def f(x):
    r = g(x)
    s = h(r)
    return s
```

If I run `python test.py call-graph-example.py`, I get the following directed graph:

[image]

The above graph correctly shows arrows going from function `f` to functions `g` and `h`, and function `g` to function `h` as provided in the source code.

However, if I introduce a nested function `i` as shown in the source code below:

```py
def g(x):
    def i(x):
        return h(x)

    return x
def h(x):
    return x*7

def f(x):
    r = g(x)
    s = h(r)
    return s
```

And run `python test.py nested-call-graph-example.py`, I get the following (incorrect) call graph:

[image]

The reason this is incorrect is the arrow going from function `g` to function `h`. This occurs because the `ast.Call` node in line 3 gets visited twice. Once when I walk the `ast.FunctionDef` representing function `g` and then again when I walk the `ast.FunctionDef` representing function `i`.

I've considered various approaches involving the following:

- Use of `ast.iter_child_nodes` in conjunction to `ast.walk`
- Introducing a way to access parent nodes as proposed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570992/getting-parent-of-ast-node-in-python)

I can't really come up with a robust way to generate this graph. How do I extend/improve my algorithm so it can handle nested functions?

Comment: Another problem is that you assume that every function name is unique, which is not necessarily the case. Nested functions are in the scope in which they are defined, so two different functions can include definitions of nested functions with the same name. However, there is no relationship between these functions. Moreover, if a nested function is stored somewhere or returned from the function which created it, its name becomes more or less irrelevant and it's quite difficult to know when it might be called. Perhaps that's outside of your needs.

Comment: @rici That's another problem I overlooked. I guess it would be nice if the call graph I generate could account for that. If not, I'd be alright with assuming all the functions have different names for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of using `ast.iter_child_nodes` is indeed the right one. One possible strategy is to use this function to manually walk the ast in a depth-first manner. Along the way, you need to keep track of the inner most function definition.

Below is a bit of an outline of how you could do this. For simplicity, my code just returns a set of tuples. Each tuple `(x, y)` means that function `x` calls function `y`. However, you can change all of this to fit your own needs.

I'll also try to give some hints on how to deal with identically named functions. However, covering all possible ways of naming and re-naming functions would be impossible.

```
def build_function_call_relation(tree: ast.AST) -> set[tuple[str, str]]:
    return set(walk_ast(tree))


def walk_ast(node: ast.AST, current_function: str | None= None) -> typing.Iterator[tuple[str, str]]:
    for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(node):
        if isinstance(child, ast.FunctionDef):
            if current_function is not None:
                new_function_name = f'{current_function}.{child.name}'
            else:
                new_function_name = child.name 
            yield from walk_ast(child, new_function_name)
        elif isinstance(child, ast.Call) and current_function is not None:
            target_name = resolve_function_name(child.func)
            if target_name is not None:
                yield (current_function, target_name)
        else:
            yield from walk_ast(child, current_function)


def resolve_function_name(node: ast.AST) -> str | None:
    match node:
        case ast.Name(id=name):
            return name 
        case _:
            return None
```

For your given snippet of source code, this gives the following output:

```
{('f', 'g'), ('g.i', 'h'), ('f', 'h')}
```

However, this code is lacking something. Suppose that we change your function `g` to

```
def g(x):
    def i(x):
        return h(x)
    return i(x)
```

If we were to run the code above, we would get the output

```
{('f', 'g'), ('g.i', 'h'), ('f', 'h'), ('g', 'i')}
```

Note that tuple `('g', 'i')`. Ideally, the second entry would be `g.i`. The dynamic nature of Python makes it impossible to determine with 100% certainty what function will be called at runtime. However, assuming functions are not rebound (using `globals`, `locals`, or assignment), we can do some best-effort guessing.

For this, we first need some knowledge about scoping in Python. In the above example, `g` would first look for `i` in its local scope, and then in the global scope. Similarly, if we were to define another function `h` in the body of `g`, this function would be called by `i` in stead of the module level function `h`. Hence, names are resolved from the narrowest scope to the widest scope. Alhough I am not 100% sure, I believe `global` and `nonlocal` can have no effect on this; and if they had, code using that would be rather exotic.

So, the problem is that we now also need scoping information. The problem with this, is that we can only obtain this using a breadth-first traversal of the AST. This is because, in the body of the function `g`, we must know whether `h` will be redefined so that we know what function will be called by `i`.

The following code incorporates a search of the direct children of the current node to get a list of all defined function names per scope, and passes this information down while walking the AST. We can use this information to guess what function will be called:

```
# Note: the scopes are stored as a list of tuples.
# Each tuple in the list is a scope.
# The first entry in the tuple is the name of the scope.
# The second entry is a set of all names defined in that scope.
# By going through the list from back to front, we can resolve
# what function will be called from a given point in the program.

def build_function_call_relation(tree: ast.AST) -> set[tuple[str, str]]:
    module_scope_functions = get_defined_functions_for_scope(tree)
    return set(walk_ast(tree, None, [('', module_scope_functions)]))


def walk_ast(node: ast.AST,
             current_function: str | None, 
             scopes) -> typing.Iterator[tuple[str, str]]:
    for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(node):
        if isinstance(child, ast.FunctionDef):
            if current_function is not None:
                new_function_name = f'{current_function}.{child.name}'
            else:
                new_function_name = child.name 
            local_scope = get_defined_functions_for_scope(child)
            yield from walk_ast(child, new_function_name, scopes + [(new_function_name, local_scope)])
        elif isinstance(child, ast.Call) and current_function is not None:
            target_name = resolve_function_name(child.func)
            if target_name is not None:
                yield (current_function, resolve_scope(target_name, scopes))
        else:
            yield from walk_ast(child, current_function, scopes)


def resolve_function_name(node: ast.AST) -> str | None:
    match node:
        case ast.Name(id=name):
            return name 
        case _:
            return None 


def get_defined_functions_for_scope(node: ast.AST) -> set[str]:
    return {
        child.name 
        for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(node) 
        if isinstance(child, ast.FunctionDef)
    }

def resolve_scope(function_name, scopes) -> str:
    for scope_name, scope in reversed(scopes):
        if function_name in scope:
            if scope_name == '':
                return function_name
            return f'{scope_name}.{function_name}'
    raise ValueError(f'Cannot find definition of function {function_name}')
```

Running this code with the modified function `g` indeed returns

```
{('g', 'g.i'), ('f', 'h'), ('f', 'g'), ('g.i', 'h')}
```

Note that this code is somewhat experimental. I have not tested what it will do when it encounters the use of functions from other modules, or what will happen when a function is invoked from the top/module scope. The code is also limited in the sense that it only detects functions defined using the `def` keyword: it does not work nicely with decorators, `globals`, `locals`, assignment etc.

---

If you are okay with generating call graphs dynamically, you could also consider hooking into `sys.settrace` and collecting the call graph information dynamically at runtime, in stead of doing it statically using the AST.